# Unable to add an UI extension on Contentful. When i run nopm run start, I get a 404 error on ui_config

Tags: contentful, contentful-management

I am new to contentful. I am trying to develop an UI extension on Contentful using Contentful SDK.

I followed all the steps mentioned in [this article](https://github.com/contentful/create-contentful-extension).

This is the code I have in index.js.

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { TextInput , Button } from '@contentful/forma-36-react-components';
import { init } from 'contentful-ui-extensions-sdk';
import '@contentful/forma-36-react-components/dist/styles.css';
import './index.css';

export class App extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    sdk: PropTypes.object.isRequired
  };

  detachExternalChangeHandler = null;

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: props.sdk.field.getValue() || ''
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.sdk.window.startAutoResizer();

    // Handler for external field value changes (e.g. when multiple authors are working on the same entry).
    this.detachExternalChangeHandler = this.props.sdk.field.onValueChanged(this.onExternalChange);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    if (this.detachExternalChangeHandler) {
      this.detachExternalChangeHandler();
    }
  }

  onExternalChange = value => {
    this.setState({ value });
  };

  onChange = e => {
    const value = e.currentTarget.value;
    this.setState({ value });
    if (value) {
      this.props.sdk.field.setValue(value);
    } else {
      this.props.sdk.field.removeValue();
    }
  };
  onButtonClick = async () => {
   console.log('hurray');
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Button buttonType="primary" isFullWidth={false}
      onClick={this.onButtonClick}>
      Add Content from AEM DAM
      </Button>
    );
  }
}
```

Ideally i am trying to create an UI extension to be used in contentful space. I downloaded the contentful SDK and i have put in a button. But I receive this error on the console and it doesn't work
Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Please post some code.

Comment: @MichaelRibbons added the code. Thank you

Comment: Good job Vandanna, your have a much better chance of getting an answer now. Sorry I can't help further, I was just looking at the review queues.

Comment: Is your code sample complete? I can't see any imports.

Comment: Hey @MichaelRibbons yes.. I added the imports in the code.. didn't paste it here.. Anyways I have updated the code here

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/contentful/create-contentful-extension

> Go to the content of this Content Type and enable mixed content at
>   your browser so that development version that is served from your
>   local machine could be rendered within https://app.contentful.com.

Better yet:

> I'm not the biggest fan of disabling the mixed content setting in browsers. Can I use HTTPS in development mode?
>   Yes, you can serve your extension using HTTPS. Add --https to start command.
>
> "start": "contentful-extension-scripts start --https",
>   It uses Parcel HTTPS under the hood , which generates a self-signed certificate, you might have to configure your browser to allow self-signed certificates for localhost.

I think that will fix the 404 error and get things working.

Please follow the readme carefully and post a separate question if you still have problems.

Comment: Thank you.. I tried enabling the mixed content. and I am still getting this 404 error on ui_config. I don't see the Mixed content error on my browsr. but I see the 404 error on the UI config

Comment: I can see a mixed content warning in your screen shot. Try using the https method.